# Unable to delete address from Address Book , My Account (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, customer-account, address

I am not able to delete the additional address from the address book.

Code for script

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    ".page-main": {
        "address": {
            "deleteAddress": "div.mobile-address-edit a[role='delete-address']",
            "deleteUrlPrefix": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getDeleteUrl())) ?>id/",
            "addAddress": "button[role='add-address']",
            "addAddressLocation": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getAddAddressUrl())) ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

phtml which I changed

```
 <div class="mobile-address-edit">
                <a class="action edit address-edit" id= "<?= $_address->getId() ?>" data-json="<?php echo htmlentities($json, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" >
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit')) ?></span>
                </a>

                <a class="action delete" href="#" role="delete-address" data-address="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_address->getId()) ?>">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Delete ')) ?></span>
                </a>
   </div>
```

It gives me this error.

[image]

I don't know what is the issue. I am not able to figure out

Answer (score 0):

*Hi I solved it by writing my own controller*

```
<?php


 namespace YX\Catalog\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class DeleteAddress extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

  protected $_addressRepository;
  protected $resultJsonFactory;

/**
 * Execute action based on request and return result
 *
 * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
 */


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context


)
{
    $this->_addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    // TODO: Implement execute() method.

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $addressId = $request->getParam('address_id');
    // $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost("address_id");

    $returnArray = [];

    try{

        $this->_addressRepository->deleteById($addressId);
        return  $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => true,'message' => $this->messageManager->addSuccess("Successfully deleted customer address")]);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {

        $delete_error  = $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        return  $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['success' => false,'message' => $this->messageManager->addError('Address cannot be deleted')]);

    }
  }
}
```

And calling this controller using `ajax` call.